# strpos still returning when false

Tags: php, function, strpos

```
$post_id = 228;

$content_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link){
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $avoid  = array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg');

    if (strpos($href, $avoid) == false) {
        echo $link->nodeValue, '<br>';
        echo $href, '<br>';
    }
}
```

strpos is still returning the urls when false - any idea what I am missing? `!==` doesn't work either.

Added info: I am trying to exclude all image urls, so if you have a better way - feel free to share.

Update, does not do the trick either . (tried this using the documentation).

```
    foreach ($links as $link){
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $avoid  = array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg');
    $pos = strpos($href, $avoid);

    if ($pos === false) {

    echo $link->nodeValue, '<br>';
    echo $href, '<br>';
   }
   }
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: [`strpos` does not take an array as the second argument.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: so how would one add more than one needle to strpos. I have looked at the documentation, but I'm still learning

Comment: Your update changes nothing. You are still passing an array as the second argument to `strpos`.

Comment: I understand @SeanBright, but the documentation here says its possible? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php ... or am I being silly and missing something?

Comment: @Remco, nothing on that page says that you can pass an array as the second argument to `strpos`.

Comment: I was checking the examples
`<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);`

Comment: @Remco, and in that example `$findme` is not an array. You are trying to pass an array. I don't know how many ways I can say the same thing.

Comment: @SeanBright A damn, why am I being so stupid... Sorry, I completely misread the examples. Thanks for repeating yourself. I clearly need a break!

Comment: @Remco, you aren’t stupid. We just weren’t effectively communicating.

Comment: Ha thanks @SeanBright. That was my fault though, so thanks again. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check if `$href` contains any of the strings in `$avoid`, you can replace them with nothing and see if you still have the original string.

```
if ($href == str_replace($avoid, '', $href)) { ...
```

`str_replace` can take an array, unlike `strpos`.

Comment: Clever. I like it.

Comment: very clean solution and avoid regex like mine

Answer (score 2):

`Warning: strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer`. Use another way, like preg_match:

```
$href = 'aaa.jpeg';
preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.jpeg)/', $href, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

if(empty($matches)) {
    //not match...
}
```

Comment: I assume this way would probably be quicker, but not sure